# AlertDialog error "PositiveButton"

Tags: android

I am trying to make a Alert Dialog , but the following code "setNegativeButton" and "setPositiveButton" become red , thats mean there are some error ,
what should I do ?
Thanks!

```
`enter code here`AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(GameActivity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Game Over!");
            alertDialog.setMessage(" Total time " + String.valueOf(timeSpent));
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }

            });
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Restart", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }

            });
            alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Please also post the error message

Answer (score 1):

You must setPositiveButton not in AlertDialog but in AllertDialog.Builder().

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(GameActivity.this)
        .setTitle("Game Over!")
        .setMessage(" Total time " + String.valueOf(timeSpent))
        .setPositiveButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }

        })
        .setNegativeButton("Restart", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }

        })
        .create();

alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(GameActivity.this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Game Over!");
    alertDialog.setMessage(" Total time " + String.valueOf(timeSpent));
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,"Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }

    });
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Restart", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }

    });
    alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this way :

```
AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    ad.setTitle("TITLE");
    ad.setCancelable(true);
    ad.setMessage("MESSAGE");
    ad.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        } });



    ad.show();
```